# Is it possible to mount a virtual disk as a drive?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, dd, devices, loop-device

I'm building Linux From Scratch. Fun project. Anyways, I've created a 60 gigabyte raw disk image using dd and filled it with /dev/zero.

I can't find anything online about how to mount the image as an actual disk. Everything I read tells me that I need to mount each individual partition and not the disk itself.

Is there a way I could mount the 60 gigs of unpartitioned space as 1 device? Much like you would see an unformatted flash drive as sdb instead of sdb1 etc.

I have pretty much tried variants of: `sudo mount -o loop disk /media/LFS`

I always get this:

```
The device '/dev/loop0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Comment: What methods did you try?

Comment: Anwar Pretty much variants of: sudo mount -o loop disk /media/LFS

Comment: is `disk` the name of your file. Is there a folder in `/media/LFS`?

Comment: disk is the name of my file. There is no folder in /media/LFS

Comment: /media/LFS should an empty folder if you want to mount on it

Comment: /media/LFS is an empty folder. There's just no folder inside of it.

Comment: Before you can mount your file as a virtual disk, it must have a partition table and be formatted to some kind of file system. And you will probably need a '-t fstype' in the mount command.

Answer (score 1):

You can not mount a disk or partition without having a filesystem on that. As the file `disk` contains all zeros there is not any filesystem on that.

First, to create a loop device on that file call

`sudo losetup -f disk`

which will create a loop device for the file 'disk'. With `sudo losetup` you will get a list of loop devices; note the one that is connected with your disk. I assume `/dev/loop0`from now on.

Next to create a valid filesystem, you have to call

`sudo mkfs -t [type] /dev/loop0`

where [type] means the filesystem type, e.g. ext4. For more options see `man mkfs`.

Now you are able to mount:

`sudo mount /dev/loop0 /media/LFS`

which should then be accessible as normal filesystem.

To disconnect, you have to unmount (`sudo umount /media/LFS`) and detach the loop device (`sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0`). From then on, you can mount the filesystem as you tried in your question (mounting with -o loop will create the loop device for you).

And no, you do not need to have the device partitioned. And you may of course mount a filesystem on a non-empty folder - but then you cannot access the previous contents of this folder before you unmount again.

**Edit**

If you want the image file to work like partitioned disks and be recognized by the kernel, you may follow the answer given in [how to format...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209566/how-to-format-a-partition-inside-of-an-img-file). In short:

Partition the image: `# fdisk disk` which will run fdisk as usual and you may create partitions.

Create Filesystems: As mkfs does not work with `whole disks` if they are partitioned (just may use the raw disk as one filesystem as stated above), you best use loop device with `partprobe`or `kpartx` to inform the kernel. The simplest way is to run `# sudo losetup -f -P disk`, which will create partition devices as e.g. `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2` etc. These may then be used by `mkfs`.

Use `gparted`: As gparted calls the default tools like `parted` and `mkfs`, the points above hold true as well. You can call `# sudo gparted disk` and then partition the disk, but you cannot format those partitions, as `mkfs` then asks for distinct images like `disk1`, `disk2` etc. So you should use the loop device with gparted as well:

```
# sudo losetup --show -f -P disk
/dev/loop0
# sudo gparted /dev/loop0
```

(I used `--show` here so `losetup` will show which device is created). 
Now you are able to work with gparted as usual. The partitions, when created/formatted, will then be available to other applications like filemanagers (maybe you have to issue `sudo partprobe /dev/loop0` for the kernel to recognize the partitions).

I did not manage to get the loop device shown in `gparted` when called without directly passing the name of the loop device, even after issuing `partprobe` or `kpartx`, e.g. when starting from the system menu. It only shows /dev/sdx devices. Maybe someone else is able to solve this issue.

Comment: How would I "plug" it into the system in a way that the disk would be seen by gparted? I am aware that I can use 'gparted disk' in the terminal but would like my computer to see it as an actual drive.

Comment: I edited the answer for using partitioned images; this may not really answer the question in your comment, but I could not find how `gparted` is able to see loop devices (or mapped devices, which could be a solution as well).